# redirect traffic with iptables to local port

Tags: redirect, iptables, nat

I have a machine IP1 that sends packets to port 54321 of IP2. I want to redirect this requests to a port 8080 of IP1 before these packets leave machine IP1 and go to IP2. This means I need to filter outcoming traffic.

I tried answers from related questions but this does not help:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d IP1 --dport 54321 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 54321 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Reading definitions of DNAT and REDIRECT still leave me confused what should work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 54321 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: According to this link PREROUTING works for incoming, not for outcoming traffic. And I have outcoming

Comment: But if you change the source ip to 127.0.0.1 you send rewrite all packages from 127.0.0.1:54321 to 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: This does not work:( I have mitmproxy on port 8080 on IP1 machine and want to forward him these packets before they are sent to another machine IP2. When I do the written command , no packets are printed with mitmproxy.

Comment: Try this: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 54321 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: I have update the big answer text, that every on can find the code at the first look.